# Convert a date/time so it can be inserted into MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a date in this format "Wed, 26 Oct 2022 16:11:30 -1100", need to convert it to UTC time and in a format so it can be inserted into a MySQL database.

The date was pulled from an email using "$headerInfo->date;".  I don't see any way to receive the date any different.

Every way I try to do the conversion is painful and brute force.

Is there an elegant, or not painful way to do this?

TIA.

Been trying regex but it doesn't handle converting the month into digits, then you have the UTC offset (time zone) to work with.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempts so we know where to begin helping

Comment: `strtotime` seems to parse that just fine…!?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the date/time string using [DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php), set the timezone to UTC then [format](https://www.php.net/manual/datetime.format.php) it to MySQL's [datetime literal syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

```php
$dt = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('D, j M Y H:i:s O', $dateString);
$mysqlFormat = $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/G7RBG

Comment: Even just `new DateTimeImmutable($dateString)` seems to works just fine.

Comment: @deceze I've had enough non-US date strings (dd/mm) interpreted incorrectly to not trust implicit parsing

Comment: Yes, but "26 Oct" is fairly unambiguous, and the format as such is pretty standard. But indeed, it's not a bad idea to fix the exact format you're expecting and have it produce an error if some other format is being passed, than to get random garbage as output.

Comment: @deceze it's more of a personal, general approach to date parsing

Comment: @Phil thank you so much!  I had read tens of posts on the same topic but they weren't dealing with a word & time zone.  Many mahalos!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//just use strtotime
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s e',strtotime('Wed, 26 Oct 2022 16:11:30 -1100'));
?>
```

Comment: FYI there shouldn't be a space between the seconds and timezone offset

Comment: The most important function is the strtotime() that converts human readable dates to epoch then manipulate it back using the inbuilt date function in PHP